# react-native expo app Failed building JavaScript bundle

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am in a monorepo with yarn workspace and I have, as the doc recommends, the main this way:

```
"main": "__generated __ / AppEntry.js",
```

but when I start the application I have this error:

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
__generated __ / AppEntry.js: Transformer is not a constructor
```

there is my AppEntry.js :

```
import 'expo/build/Expo.fx';
import { activateKeepAwake } from 'expo-keep-awake';
import registerRootComponent from 'expo/build/launch/registerRootComponent';
import App from '../App';
if (__DEV__) {
  activateKeepAwake();
}
registerRootComponent(App);
```

Do you know where it could come from?
ps: new project with new version of expo ,react-native ;)